# Directional derivative of the $\ell_1$ norm

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The following paragraph is taken from Nocedal and Wright's *Numerical Optimization* (p. 628 of the second edition).

> Consider for instance the $\ell_1$ norm function $f(x)=\|x\|_1$. We have from the definition (A.51) that
>   $$
> D(\|x\|_1;p)
> =\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\|x+\epsilon p\|_1-\|x\|_1}\epsilon
> =\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i+\epsilon p_i|-\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|}\epsilon.
> $$
>   If $x_i>0$, we have $|x_i+\epsilon p_i|=|x_i|+\epsilon p_i$ for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small. If $x_i<0$, we have $|x_i+\epsilon p_i|=|x_i|-\epsilon p_i$, while if $x_i=0$, we have $|x_i+\epsilon p_i|=\epsilon|p_i|$. Therefore, we have
>   $$
> D(\|x\|_1;p)
> =\sum_{i|x_i<0}-p_i+\sum_{i|x_i>0}p_i+\sum_{i|x_i=0}|p_i|,
> $$
>   so the directional derivative of this function exists for any $x$ and $p$.

How do they obtain that $|x_i+\epsilon p_i|=\epsilon|p_i|$ when $x_i=0$? It seems that it should be $|x_i+\epsilon p_i|=|\epsilon||p_i|$. Then the limits when $\epsilon\downarrow0$ and $\epsilon\uparrow0$ do not coincide and hence the derivative does not exist. Is it true that the $\ell_1$ norm has directional derivatives for any $x$ and $p$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You're right. For $x=0$, from what they write we have $$\frac{\lVert \varepsilon p\rVert_1}{\varepsilon} = \frac{\lvert \varepsilon\rvert}{\varepsilon} \cdot \lVert p\rVert_1$$ which I very much doubt has a limit for non-zero $p$. This boils down, eventually, to the one-dimensional case of the absolute value not being differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you very much for your comment. I checked a number of references and I was not able to find a definition of the directional derivative with a one-sided limit. I think there is a mistake in Nocedal and Wright's book.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of directional derivative you always take limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ through positive values. The limit through negative values is the directional derivative along $-p$. For example, in the real line case $|x|$ has  a derivative in both the positive and the negative directions of the origin even though the function is not differentiable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (+1)! That makes sense. In this situation, I think it would be nice to use the notation $\epsilon\downarrow0$ for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I am not sure I buy this. Pretty much every book is usually very clear in when the limite is only taken wrt positive values, and this one is as well. Further, looking for instance at the French wikipedia page (the only one to mention directional derivatives), there is an alternative explicit definition for that, [attributed to Dini.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e_directionnelle#D%C3%A9riv%C3%A9e_directionnelle_au_sens_de_Dini) So, not the standard one.

Comment: For an example where the very same textbook has no issue specifying one-sided limits, look no further than (A.40) only a few pages before: $$\lim_{x\downarrow x_0} f(x)=f(0)$$ why do that here, but then "forget" to mention anywhere, in particular in the definition and notation, that later one wants explicitly $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$?

Comment: Clement is right. The limit in the definition of the directional derivative is the usual two-sided limit. Nocedal and Wright use one-sided limits and they use special notation for that ($\downarrow$).

Comment: Some authors even stress that the limit is two-sided (see [here](http://www2.math.technion.ac.il/~mcwikel/h2m/DirectionalDerivatives.pdf)): _In this document I want to stress, as you should have understood from lectures and from books, that the limit is the usual limit, i.e. a two-sided limit. It is NOT a one sided limit_. Of course, this is a definition, so we can do whatever we want, but it seems that the usual definition is with a two-sided limit.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Yes, I am aware of the fact that there are two inconsistent definitions. Intuitively I feel that the derivative in the direction of a vector $v$ should not be the same as the derivative in the direction of  $-v$. If you want make sense of the argument given in the book you have to adapt the definition I have suggested.